# How to create a Marshmallow SQL schema for GeoJson

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, geojson, shapely, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an `API` using flask, `SQLAlchemy`, `Marshmallow`, `PostGIS` that return `GeoJson` `FeatureCollection`. I want to be able to work with any Geo Objects (`Point`, `Polygone`,...).

I tried many things but never successfully recreated the `GeoJson` `FeatureCollection` format. It is possible to force a shape to a marshmallow schema ?

This is SQLAlchemy model:

```
class Locations(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: int = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    linename: str = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    point = db.Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

This is my marshmallow schema,

```
    class LocationsSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
        point = fields.Method('wkt_to_geojson')

        def wkt_to_geojson(self, obj):
            return {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'linename': obj.linename}, 'geometry': shapely.geometry.mapping(to_shape(obj.point))}

        class Meta:
            model = Locations

locations_schema = LocationsSchema(many=True, only=["point"])
```

This is my blueprint route:

```
@map_data_blueprint.route('/locations', methods=['GET'])
def all_items():
    locations = Locations.query.all()

    serialized = locations_schema.dump(locations)
    return jsonify(serialized)
```

This is the json I receive from the API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "point": {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          6.130649, 
          49.609332
        ], 
        "type": "Point"
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "linename": "1"
      }, 
      "type": "Feature"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": 3, 
    "point": {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          6.126288, 
          49.598557
        ], 
        "type": "Point"
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "linename": "1"
      }, 
      "type": "Feature"
    }
  }]
```

But I am trying to get the `FeatureCollection` `Geojson` format here is an example [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by combining geoalchemy2.shape, shapely and geojson package. I removed the marshmallow layer for this specific API as I have not found a way with the marshmallow layer.

```
def parse_geojson(obj):
    geo = shapely.geometry.mapping(to_shape(obj.point))
    if geo:
        return geojson.Feature(
            id=obj.id,
            geometry=geo,
            properties={
                "linename": obj.linename
            })

@map_data_blueprint.route('/locations', methods=['GET'])
def all_items():
    locations = Locations.query.all()  
    features = [parse_geojson(location) for location in locations]
    serialized = geojson.dumps(geojson.FeatureCollection(features))
    return serialized
```

I don't know if it is best practice to serialize the query answer in the route or not but this works.